# confirm() incorrectly always stops default actions on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I'm testing a website **on an iPad** to make sure it works. I'm encountering a problem which I can't seem to fix:

Adding a confirm to an event stops the action of an element (anchoring/submitting):

```
var touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
$('.Back2Overview').on(touchEvent, function(e){
    if( !confirm('Some Question') ){ alert(1); e.preventDefault(); }
    else{ alert(2);}
});
```

**When clicking the `.Back2Overview` I get prompted the question:**
If I press [CANCEL] I get `1` alerted and no further action is taken, as expected.
If I press [OK] I get `2` alerted, as expected, but no further action is taken, **which is unwanted**.

I simplefied the page. `myPage.html` **ONLY** contains this, not a byte more:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="/beheer/klanten/">Terug</a>

<script>
    var touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').on(touchEvent, function(e){
            confirm('Some Question');
        });
    });
</script>
```

it still never actually continues with the default action. The submitter wont submit and, in this particular case, the anchor doesnt work. When I'm *really fast* after a prompt, *sometimes* it'll work.

- No other code conflicts with this part of the html.
- Works perfectly fine in Firefox(31), IE8 and Chrome(36)

Comment: When are you hooking this event up? Are you doing it before `$(document).ready`? Furthermore, where in the document are you loading this script?

Comment: in the ready(), in an `<script>` tag. As I've mentioned the code does run, I get the alerts, which shouldn't if the code is in the wrong place

Comment: But you didn't really answer the question of **where** in the document you're including the script. If you're including it anywhere but *right before* the ending tag of the body you can have unexpected results in different browsers.

Comment: It is in a document-ready, before the html. Shouldn't matter, because it happends in tjhe doc-ready. Tested this, and it indeed doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Don't use `touchstart` as event, just use `click`.

**Longer answer:**
"Back in the days" iOS didn't support the `click` event, instead they had `touchstart` and `touchstop`.
I tried to fix this with `.on('click touchstart')`, but Android catches those both, and would trigger the previous example twice, one for `click` and one for `touchstart`.

The fix at the time was to see if `touchstart` was supported, or fall back to `click` (browsers).
Seems like they've updated, you can use click now. Tested this on a iPad 1, so old devices shouldn't be a problem either.